# VS 2015 RC Apache Cordova Blank appTemplate Build Failed

Tags: android, apache, visual-studio, cordova, visual-studio-2015

I Installed VS 2015 preview and Tools For Apache Cordova. Creating blank Apache Cordova project and I can't build the app or run on android ripple.
I'm sure checked all necessary tools while installing visual studio and They installed successfully.

output:

```
All packages are already installed and there is nothing to restore.
NuGet package restore finished.
1>------ Build started: Project: BlankCordovaApp17, Configuration: Debug Android ------
1>Build started 5/24/2015 8:29:15 PM.
1>Building with tools version "14.0".
1>Target "_CheckForInvalidConfigurationAndPlatform" in file "C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets" from project "c:\users\******\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\BlankCordovaApp17\BlankCordovaApp17\BlankCordovaApp17.jsproj" (entry point):
1>Task "Error" skipped, due to false condition; ( '$(_InvalidConfigurationError)' == 'true' ) was evaluated as ( '' == 'true' ).
1>Task "Warning" skipped, due to false condition; ( '$(_InvalidConfigurationWarning)' == 'true' ) was evaluated as ( '' == 'true' ).
1>Using "Message" task from assembly "Microsoft.Build.Tasks.Core, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a".
1>Task "Message"
1>  Configuration=Debug
1>Done executing task "Message".
1>Task "Message"
1>  Platform=Android
1>Done executing task "Message".
1>Task "Error" skipped, due to false condition; ('$(OutDir)' != '' and !HasTrailingSlash('$(OutDir)')) was evaluated as ('bin\Android\Debug\' != '' and !HasTrailingSlash('bin\Android\Debug\')).
1>Task "Error" skipped, due to false condition; ('$(BaseIntermediateOutputPath)' != '' and !HasTrailingSlash('$(BaseIntermediateOutputPath)')) was evaluated as ('bld\' != '' and !HasTrailingSlash('bld\')).
1>Task "Error" skipped, due to false condition; ('$(IntermediateOutputPath)' != '' and !HasTrailingSlash('$(IntermediateOutputPath)')) was evaluated as ('bld\Android\Debug\' != '' and !HasTrailingSlash('bld\Android\Debug\')).
1>Done building target "_CheckForInvalidConfigurationAndPlatform" in project "BlankCordovaApp17.jsproj".
1>Target "EntityDeploy" skipped, due to false condition; ('@(EntityDeploy)' != '') was evaluated as ('' != '').
1>Target "BeforeBuild" in file "C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v14.0\ApacheCordovaTools\vs-mda-targets\Microsoft.MDA.FileMirroring.targets" from project "c:\users\******\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\BlankCordovaApp17\BlankCordovaApp17\BlankCordovaApp17.jsproj" (target "Build" depends on it):
1>Done building target "BeforeBuild" in project "BlankCordovaApp17.jsproj".
1>Target "CoreBuild" in file "C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v14.0\ApacheCordovaTools\vs-mda-targets\Microsoft.MDA.FileMirroring.targets" from project "c:\users\******\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\BlankCordovaApp17\BlankCordovaApp17\BlankCordovaApp17.jsproj" (target "Build" depends on it):
1>Done building target "CoreBuild" in project "BlankCordovaApp17.jsproj".
1>Target "CreateTfsBuildInfoResource" skipped, due to false condition; ( $(AddBuildInfoToAssembly)==true ) was evaluated as ( false==true ).
1>Target "AfterBuild" in file "C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v14.0\ApacheCordovaTools\vs-mda-targets\Microsoft.MDA.FileMirroring.targets" from project "c:\users\******\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\BlankCordovaApp17\BlankCordovaApp17\BlankCordovaApp17.jsproj" (target "Build" depends on it):
1>Done building target "AfterBuild" in project "BlankCordovaApp17.jsproj".
1>Target "BuildOnlySettings" in file "C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets" from project "c:\users\******\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\BlankCordovaApp17\BlankCordovaApp17\BlankCordovaApp17.jsproj" (target "Build" depends on it):
1>Done building target "BuildOnlySettings" in project "BlankCordovaApp17.jsproj".
1>Target "PreComputeCompileTypeScript" in file "C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v14.0\TypeScript\Microsoft.TypeScript.targets" from project "c:\users\******\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\BlankCordovaApp17\BlankCordovaApp17\BlankCordovaApp17.jsproj" (target "CompileTypeScript" depends on it):
1>Using "VsTsc" task from assembly "C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v14.0\TypeScript\TypeScript.tasks.dll".
1>Task "VsTsc"
1>  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\TypeScript\1.4\tsc.exe --sourcemap --target ES5 --noEmitOnError --locale en-US  --out "c:\users\******\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\BlankCordovaApp17\BlankCordovaApp17\\www\scripts\appBundle.js" COMPUTE_PATHS_ONLY
1>Done executing task "VsTsc".
1>Using "AssignTargetPath" task from assembly "Microsoft.Build.Tasks.Core, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a".
1>Task "AssignTargetPath"
1>Done executing task "AssignTargetPath".
1>Done building target "PreComputeCompileTypeScript" in project "BlankCordovaApp17.jsproj".
1>Target "CompileTypeScript" in file "C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v14.0\ApacheCordovaTools\vs-mda-targets\Microsoft.MDA.FileMirroring.targets" from project "c:\users\******\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\BlankCordovaApp17\BlankCordovaApp17\BlankCordovaApp17.jsproj" (target "BuildRipple" depends on it):
1>Building target "CompileTypeScript" completely.
1>No input files were specified.
1>Task "VsTsc"
1>  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\TypeScript\1.4\tsc.exe --sourcemap --target ES5 --noEmitOnError --locale en-US  --out "c:\users\******\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\BlankCordovaApp17\BlankCordovaApp17\\www\scripts\appBundle.js"
1>Done executing task "VsTsc".
1>Done building target "CompileTypeScript" in project "BlankCordovaApp17.jsproj".
1>Target "PrepareForRippleRequirements" in file "C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v14.0\ApacheCordovaTools\vs-mda-targets\Microsoft.MDA.FileMirroring.targets" from project "c:\users\******\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\BlankCordovaApp17\BlankCordovaApp17\BlankCordovaApp17.jsproj" (target "BuildRipple" depends on it):
1>Using "CallTarget" task from assembly "Microsoft.Build.Tasks.Core, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a".
1>Task "CallTarget"
1>Target "EnsureNodeJsRequirementsAreAtCorrectVersion" in file "C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v14.0\ApacheCordovaTools\vs-mda-targets\Microsoft.MDA.FileMirroring.targets" from project "c:\users\******\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\BlankCordovaApp17\BlankCordovaApp17\BlankCordovaApp17.jsproj" (target "PrepareForRippleRequirements" depends on it):
1>Task "Error" skipped, due to false condition; ('$(ProjectDir.Substring(0, 2))' == '\\') was evaluated as ('c:' == '\\').
1>Task "Error" skipped, due to false condition; ($(MDAPropertiesEvaluated) == 'true' And $(NodeJsDir) == '') was evaluated as (true == 'true' And C:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs\ == '').
1>Task "Error" skipped, due to false condition; ($(MDAPropertiesEvaluated) == 'true' And $(MDAVsixDir) == '') was evaluated as (true == 'true' And C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\Extensions\ApacheCordovaTools == '').
1>Task "Error" skipped, due to false condition; ($(MDAPropertiesEvaluated) == '' And $(NodeJsDir) == '') was evaluated as (true == '' And C:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs\ == '').
1>Task "Error" skipped, due to false condition; ($(MDAPropertiesEvaluated) == '' And $(MDAVsixDir) == '') was evaluated as (true == '' And C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\Extensions\ApacheCordovaTools == '').
1>Task "Error" skipped, due to false condition; (!Exists('$(NodeJsDir)') Or !Exists('$(NodeJsDir)\node.exe')) was evaluated as (!Exists('C:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs\') Or !Exists('C:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs\\node.exe')).
1>Task "Error" skipped, due to false condition; (!Exists('$(MDAVsixDir)') Or !Exists('$(MDAVsixDir)\packages\vs-tac')) was evaluated as (!Exists('C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\Extensions\ApacheCordovaTools') Or !Exists('C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\Extensions\ApacheCordovaTools\packages\vs-tac')).
1>Task "CallTarget"
1>Target "InstallMDA" in file "C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v14.0\ApacheCordovaTools\vs-mda-targets\Microsoft.MDA.FileMirroring.targets" from project "c:\users\******\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\BlankCordovaApp17\BlankCordovaApp17\BlankCordovaApp17.jsproj" (target "EnsureNodeJsRequirementsAreAtCorrectVersion" depends on it):
1>Using "RunMdaInstall" task from assembly "C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v14.0\ApacheCordovaTools\vs-mda-targets\Microsoft.VisualStudio.MultiDeviceHybridApps.MdaBuildTasks.dll".
1>Task "RunMdaInstall"
1>  Your environment has been set up for using Node.js 0.10.33 (ia32) and npm.
1>Done executing task "RunMdaInstall".
1>Task "CallTarget" skipped, due to false condition; ($(MDAInstallErrorCode) == '-17') was evaluated as (0 == '-17').
1>Task "WriteLinesToFile" skipped, due to false condition; ($(MDAInstallErrorCode) == '-17' AND Exists('$(ProjectDir)\platforms')) was evaluated as (0 == '-17' AND Exists('c:\users\******\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\BlankCordovaApp17\BlankCordovaApp17\\platforms')).
1>Task "Delete" skipped, due to false condition; ($(MDAInstallErrorCode) == '-17' AND Exists('bld\iOS\Debug\buildInfo.json')) was evaluated as (0 == '-17' AND Exists('bld\iOS\Debug\buildInfo.json')).
1>Task "Error" skipped, due to false condition; ($(MDAInstallErrorCode) != '0' And $(MDAInstallErrorCode) != '-17') was evaluated as (0 != '0' And 0 != '-17').
1>Done building target "InstallMDA" in project "BlankCordovaApp17.jsproj".
1>Done executing task "CallTarget".
1>Done building target "EnsureNodeJsRequirementsAreAtCorrectVersion" in project "BlankCordovaApp17.jsproj".
1>Done executing task "CallTarget".
1>Using "MdaVsCli" task from assembly "C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v14.0\ApacheCordovaTools\vs-mda-targets\Microsoft.VisualStudio.MultiDeviceHybridApps.MdaBuildTasks.dll".
1>Task "MdaVsCli"
1>  C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe /s /c " C:\Users\******\AppData\Roaming\npm\vs-tac-cli.cmd prepare --platform Android --configuration Debug --projectDir . --projectName BlankCordovaApp17 --npmInstallDir C:\Users\******\AppData\Roaming\npm --language en-US"
1>  'C:\Users\******\AppData\Roaming\npm\vs-tac-cli.cmd' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
1>  operable program or batch file.
1>Done executing task "MdaVsCli" -- FAILED.
1>Done building target "PrepareForRippleRequirements" in project "BlankCordovaApp17.jsproj" -- FAILED.
1>
1>Build FAILED.
1>
1>Time Elapsed 00:00:01.91
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
========== Deploy: 0 succeeded, 0 failed, 0 skipped ==========
```

Comment: is it a typescript project? did you try the JavaScript project?

Comment: preview means Visual Studio 2015 Community RC?  I'm using it with JavaScript cordova project without your problem

Comment: No, it is a JavaScript project

Comment: yes I mean Visual Studio 2015 Community RC

Comment: cordova cache cleared? your preview version = Community RC version?

Comment: How can I clear cordova cache?, yes I'm using Visual Studio 2015 Community RC

Comment: I was using vs 2013 Community update 4 with tools for apache cordova ctp3.1  in that version, it is said that the project cannot be built if there is SPACE in the project folder name, I'm not sure this bug still present in vs 2015

Comment: in options - tools for apache cordova - click clear cache - system hangs for a minute or two, wait, then ok.

Comment: Now I realized first time I attempted to build the app my Internet connection had some issues so visual studio didn't received necessary packages it needed in first run, clearing cordova cache solved my problem, please submit your answer and I'll choose it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in options - tools for apache cordova - click clear cache - system hangs for a minute or two, wait, then ok.

Comment: Now I realized first time I attempted to build the app my Internet connection had some issues so visual studio didn't received necessary packages it needed in first run, clearing cordova cache solved my problem, mercy