# Problems with Cordova in VS 2015 - Error MSB4044 The "RunMdaInstall" task was not given a value for the > required parameter "NpmInstallDir"

Tags: cordova, visual-studio-2015

I am new to Cordova, so I have just installed VS 2015 and the tools required for running Cordova.

I created  a new project (Hello World) and try to run the index.html under debug/Android/Ripple-Nexus(Galaxy) and gets the following error:

> Error MSB4044  The "RunMdaInstall" task was not given a value for the
>   required parameter "NpmInstallDir". HelloWorld C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v14.0\ApacheCordovaTools\vs-mda-targets\Microsoft.MDA.FileMirroring.targets
>   287

Comment: Did you try this? http://stackoverflow.com/a/30427260/600559

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the tools can't find NPM on your machine. Can you check that this is true by running the dependency checker and installing anything that you're missing?

1. Go to tools -> options -> Tools for Apache Cordova.
2. Click "Run Dependency Checker."
3. Install any missing dependencies.